# CartoDB Geocoding Fails for Connecticut Cities

Tags: carto, geocoding

I uploaded a dataset that includes a bunch of cities in the state of Connecticut. One example is Farmington. I set the state column to the column with the state abbreviations (it uses "CT") and used text "USA" for the country. All the city and state combinations outside Connecticut geocoded fine, but the Connecticut ones, which make up a majority of this dataset, all failed. Is this a technical error or am I missing some kind of magic thing I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now. We had an issue with the Connecticut state: it wasn't recognised properly. It is now, so this issue should no longer be happening to anyone.

Remember to remove the cartodb_georef_status column and try again!